# What is the limit without using l'Hopital's rule.

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

$$
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1-\cos x}{x\sin 2x}
$$

So I was thinking of separating it into two parts, one is $(1-\cos(x))/x$ and the other one is $1/\sin(2x)$. The limit for the first part is 0, but I don't know what to do for the second part. Am I approaching it correctly in the first place? Any hint will be great!

Comment: The limit of the second as $x \to 0^+$ is $\infty$, so you get an indeterminate form $0 \cdot \infty$ which doesn't help.

Comment: Even though you're not supposed to use l'Hopital in the solution, you can use it to "cheat" and see what the limit ought to be with l'Hopital, then from there prove that that's the limit without l'Hopital.

Comment: If you're allowed to use the fact that $\frac{\sin x}{x} \rightarrow 1$ as $x \rightarrow 0,$ then you can get the limit by multiplying the numerator and denominator by $1 + \cos x$ and using a couple of basic trig. identities.

Answer (score 2):

If you're allowed to use the fact that $\frac{\sin x}{x} \rightarrow 1$ as $x \rightarrow 0,$ then you can get the limit by multiplying both the numerator and the denominator by $1 + \cos x$ and using a couple of basic trig. identities:

$$  \frac{1 - \cos x}{x \sin {2x}} \cdot \frac{1 + \cos x}{1 + \cos x} \;\; = \;\; \frac{1 - \cos^2 x}{x \cdot \sin {2x} \cdot (1 + \cos x)} \;\; = \;\; \frac{\sin^2 x}{x \cdot 2 \sin x \cos x \cdot (1 + \cos x)}$$

$$ = \;\; \frac{\sin x}{2x \cos x (1 + \cos x)} \;\; = \;\; \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{\sin x}{x} \cdot \frac{1}{\cos x (1 + \cos x)} \;\; \longrightarrow \;\; \frac{1}{2} \cdot 1 \cdot \frac{1}{1\cdot 2} \;\; = \;\; \frac{1}{4} $$

Regarding your later-added comment, pretty much every trig limit you'll encounter that you're supposed to evaluate without using L'Hopital's Rule will make use of $\lim \limits_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin x}{x} = 1$ after some algebraic manipulation (which may involve using [trig conjugates](https://www.google.com/search?q=trig+conjugate+limits), which are analogous to the conjugates you sometimes use when square roots are involved) and the use of trig identities. Although many of the manipulations involved may seem a bit tricky, after a bit of practice you'll get to the point where for most problems of this type there will only be a few obvious things to try, and for textbook and class test problems, one of those obvious things is going to work.

Comment: Thank you for the tips. Will try to break down into simpler limits when I am stuck with them

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$\dfrac{1-\cos(x)}{x\sin(2x)}=$

$\dfrac{1-\cos^2(x)}{2x\sin(x)\cos(x)(1+\cos(x))}=$

$\dfrac{\sin^2(x)}{2x\sin(x)\cos(x)(1+\cos(x))}=$

$\dfrac{\sin(x)}{x}\dfrac{1}{2\cos(x)(1+\cos(x))}.$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Sounds great! Will definitely work on trying to use the trigonometric identities when stuck with limits

Comment: As you get a little practise you will not find it so hard. Similar patterns.

Answer (score 0):

If you decompose into Maclaurin series, you get $\cos x \approx 1 - x^2/2, \sin (2x) \approx 2x$. Can you use this to approximate the limit?

Comment: That's no different from l'Hopital, though.

Comment: @Arthur (1) OP has not indicated not to use L'Hospital. (2) it is in similar spirit but is somewhat of a different mechanism.

Comment: (1) Did you read the title? Or the tags? (2) the mechanism is identical if you get the series expansion by differentiating and evaluating at $x=0$. The theory behind may differ slightly, but the calculations are the same.

Comment: They do not let us use techniques we did not learn yet (even if we know them), so I cannot use L'Hopital's rule or series to find limits. I am interested in learning about the Maclaurin series now though

Comment: Do you know *equivalence* of functions?

Comment: @HatemChalak Maclaurin series are basically the same as Taylor series, and I think it's easier to find material if you search for that. The idea is that nice enough functions (including most of the ones you know the name of) are uniquely determined by all their higher order derivatives at a single point (they are called _analytic_). For instance, among these analytic functions, $\sin x$ is the _only one_ that at $x=0$ has value $0$, first derivative $1$, second derivative $0$, third derivative $-1$, and so on.

Comment: @Arthur the tag was not there when I originally read the question. Same calculations does not mean same technique...